# Flutter "Catch up" animation on drag

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently building a flutter app where a user can drag a circle around the screen. I use a Listener widget to get the current pointer position, then use a transform widget to position it accordingly.

[image: What I'm trying to build]

```
class _DraggingExample extends State<VelocityAnimations>{
  var offset = Offset(0, 0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
     // I get pointer-events here.
      body: Listener(
        onPointerMove: (e) {
          setState(() {
            // - 50 to center the container
            offset = e.localPosition - Offset(50, 50);
          });
        },
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
        child: SizedBox.expand(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Center(child: Text('Hello, World!')),
              // I transform the container here.
              Transform.translate(
                offset: offset,
                child: Container(
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It works perfectly. But it's very bland. It would be much nicer if when I move my pointer/finger, the container gradually catches up to the finger. The effect I'm looking for can be seen in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/clementGir/pen/RQqvQx). Here, the black circle gradually catches up with the mouse as you move it along.

I've tried using a Physics Simulation and plain animations, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use [AnimatedPositioned](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedPositioned-class.html) which animates its position implicitly.

The animation can be configured with `duration` and [Curves](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/Curves-class.html) as you want.

```
AnimatedPositioned(
  left: offset.dx,
  top: offset.dy,
  curve: Curves.easeOutCirc,
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
  child: Container(
    // ...
  ),
),
```